# Visual Studio Code search with "any" character

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there any characters for Visual Studio Code, like in SQL?

SQL:

```
... where like "%test%";  // Anything with "test" text inside
... where like "[test]%"; // Anything which starts with "test"
... where like "test_";   // Anything which starts with "test" and has only 1 more character
```

What are the characters in Visual Studio Code search, like shown above?

Comment: In regex mode use a `.`

Comment: Search (across files) or find in a file use a form of regular expression syntax so each of your examples can be done with a regex.  There are no search characters in vscode like you present though - you would have to make a regex for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these regular expressions would work for you.  See [regex101 test cases](https://regex101.com/r/V2RuNd/1):

`\w+test\w+     // Anything with "test" text inside`

`\btest\w*      // Anything which starts with "test"`

`\btest\w\b     // Anything which starts with "test" and has only 1 more character`

So it is not as easy as the built-in SQL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

According to Visual Studio Code documentation, [advanced search](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) section:

> In the input box below the search box, you can enter patterns to include or exclude from the search. If you enter example, that will match every folder and file named example in the workspace. If you enter ./example, that will match the folder example/ at the top level of your workspace. Use ! to exclude those patterns from the search. !example will skip searching any folder or file named example. Use , to separate multiple patterns. Paths must use forward slashes. You can also use glob syntax:
> * to match one or more characters in a path segment
> ? to match on one character in a path segment
> ** to match any number of path segments, including none
> {} to group conditions (for example {**/*.html,**/*.txt} matches all HTML and text files)
> [] to declare a range of characters to match (example.[0-9] to match on example.0, example.1, …)

Comment: These are strictly for the files to include/exclude input boxes and differ significantly from the regex patterns used in the search or find input boxes - which I believe is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. For example, how does "where like "%test%"" from the question translate to this form?

Comment: This isn't much different from a link-only answer.